# The image for my website's background won't load/display

Tags: html, css

Okay, so here's my problem. For some reason, the image that I wanted as a background for my website won't load, no matter what. I was working on the code in Notepad++. I knew that it wasn't gonna load through previous attempts with test pictures, so I decided to to push it aside, for now, to work on the actual background. But now that's done, I'm faced with the exact same problem as before, with no obvious solution. At one point, me and my tried using image{} instead of url{}. We tried moving it to the html file instead of the css file. Nothing. I have no idea whether the solution is extremely complicated or so simple that sedimentary rock could figure it out, neither do I care. I just want, nay, *need it* to work. SOS

```css
body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    transition: background-color .5s;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #17003f;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #deccff;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 16px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS\style.css">

</head>
<style>
hmtl {
 background-image: url(images folder/websitebackground.png);
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
</style>
<body>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
  <h2>Sidenav Push Example</h2>
  <p>Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu, and push this content to the right. Notice that we add a black see-through background-color to body when the sidenav is opened.</p>
</div>

<script>
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255,0,255)";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
</script>
     
</body>
</html>
```

Code-vengers, assemble!

Comment: Dont do it on html tag. Put background on body tag. Also path in url() should be in quotes.

Comment: Firstly, use `body` tag instead of `html` tag to put background image. Plus, you've misspelled `html` as `hmtl`.

Answer (score 0):

Delete this, you shouldn't do it under the html tag.

```
<style>
hmtl {
    background-image: url(images folder/websitebackground.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
</style>
```

And do it this way

```
body{
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    transition: background-color .5s;
    background-image: url(images folder/websitebackground.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Also, there is no need to do it in the html, you can add this to your css file, and make sure the url() you are using is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this. You should be doing it for body tag not html. Also the path in url needs to be quoted.

```
<style>
body {
    background-image: url("images folder/websitebackground.png");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should put the background on the body, not html
Second, I think your link's wrong, try a new right link

```css
body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    transition: background-color .5s;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #17003f;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #deccff;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 16px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS\style.css">

</head>
<style>
body {
 background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/531880/pexels-photo-531880.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=cold-vehicles-water-531880.jpg&fm=jpg);
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
</style>
<body>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
  <h2>Sidenav Push Example</h2>
  <p>Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu, and push this content to the right. Notice that we add a black see-through background-color to body when the sidenav is opened.</p>
</div>

<script>
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255,0,255)";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
</script>
     
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First Use a propper code editor . It will control your typo. Insert Background related lines in the CSS body tag. Where it should come in Body part not in the whole HTML

```
 body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    transition: background-color .5s;

    background-image: url(images folder/websitebackground.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So I moved the relevant code back to the CSS and placed it under "body", and it worked fine for me. I created a codepen for you if you need a reference:
https://codepen.io/gabor-szekely/pen/rQmWrL

```
body {   
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;   
  transition: background-color .5s;   
  background-image:   url(https://c402277.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/photos/11552/images/hero_small/rsz_namibia_will_burrard_lucas_wwf_us_1.jpg); 
  background-position: center;   
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}
```

You cannot set a background image under "html", it has to be done under "body". Also, make sure the path to the image is correct in your url(), otherwise it will obviously not work either.

Hope this helps!